# SQL Server: Getting convertion error when use ROW_NUMBER function for pagination

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have written a stored procedure which fetch data from table using pagination. I used the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_GetLastCSMSavedData
    (@Ticker VARCHAR(10)=NULL,
     @ClientName VARCHAR(10)=NULL,
     @LastCSMDate Datetime=NULL,
     @PageIndex INT = 1,
     @PageSize INT = 10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @offset INT
    SET @offset = (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize
    
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastCSMDeliveredDate DESC) AS INT) AS ''RowNumber'',
    ID,
    Ticker,
    c.ClientName,
    Earnings,
    PrePost,
    IIF([QC-ViewAllContent] IS NULL,0,1) HasViewAllContent,
    IIF([QCCommentsContent] IS NULL,0,1) HasQCCommentsContent,
    InsertedOn,
    LastCSMDeliveredDate,
    Action,
    UserName
    from tblLastCSMDelivered csm JOIN tblClient c
    ON csm.ClientCode=c.ClientCode
    WHERE LastCSMDeliveredDate IS NOT NULL) X
    WHERE CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)>='+@offset+' AND CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)<'+(@offset+@PageSize)

    IF @Ticker IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL=@SQL+' AND X.Ticker='+@Ticker
    END

    IF @ClientName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL=@SQL+' AND X.ClientName='+@ClientName
    END

    IF @LastCSMDate IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL=@SQL+' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,X.LastCSMDeliveredDate,112)=CONVERT(VARCHAR,'+@LastCSMDate+',112)'
    END

    --EXEC @SQL
    PRINT @SQL
END
```

I assume for this line

```
WHERE CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)>='+@offset+' AND CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)<'+(@offset+@PageSize)
```

I am getting a runtime error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_GetLastCSMSavedData, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 20]
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

Please tell me what I have missed in my code. Thanks

Comment: **Parameterise** your parameters, and the error goes away. Why are you using dynamic SQL here at all, when there's nothing dynamic going on here either. That, too, will cause the error to go away.

Comment: sorry not clear. my parameter @PageSize has default value.

Comment: You aren't parametrising your parameters, @Mist ... `N'...CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)>='+@offset+N'...'` isn't parametrising, it's **injecting**; it's 2021 SQL injection should have died like the Black Plague by now yet it's still alive and well in your code. But, again, why are you using dynamic SQL when the statement doesn't need to be dynamic?

Comment: @Larnu i rarely work with sql server. i do not have very good knowledge in sql server. i make the sql dynamic because data will be fetch based on filter like ticker, clientname etc. without dynamic how could i do it? can you please post a sample code here. thanks

Comment: But you could just parametrise... Again, why not parametrise? There's no need for dynamic SQL.

Comment: i do not know that approach. please show me how to achieve parametrise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct on your assumption that this line causes the error: `WHERE CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)>='+@offset+'...`

Fact is that `@offset` is an int and the rest of the line is a string and therefor SQL Server will attempt to implicitly convert the string to int according to the [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

However, I Agree with Larnu's comment, you don't need dynamic SQL for this query at all:

```
ALTER PROC USP_GetLastCSMSavedData
(
    @Ticker VARCHAR(10)=NULL,
    @ClientName VARCHAR(10)=NULL,
    @LastCSMDate Datetime=NULL,
    @PageIndex INT = 1,
    @PageSize INT = 10
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @offset INT
    SET @offset = (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastCSMDeliveredDate DESC) AS INT) AS 'RowNumber',
        ID,
        Ticker,
        c.ClientName,
        Earnings,
        PrePost,
        IIF([QC-ViewAllContent] IS NULL,0,1) HasViewAllContent,
        IIF([QCCommentsContent] IS NULL,0,1) HasQCCommentsContent,
        InsertedOn,
        LastCSMDeliveredDate,
        Action,
        UserName
        from tblLastCSMDelivered csm 
        JOIN tblClient c
            ON csm.ClientCode=c.ClientCode
        WHERE LastCSMDeliveredDate IS NOT NULL
    ) X
    WHERE CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)>= @offset  AND CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)< (@offset+@PageSize)
    AND (@Ticker IS NULL OR X.Ticker = @Ticker)
    AND (@ClientName IS NULL OR X.ClientName = @ClientName)
    -- Why bother converting here?
    AND (@LastCSMDate IS NULL OR X.LastCSMDeliveredDate = @LastCSMDate) 
END
```

Comment: Probably want to add a `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` due to "Kitchen sink".

Comment: Thank you sir for the code. i will test it and let you know. this is not clear-> `(@LastCSMDate IS NULL OR X.LastCSMDeliveredDate @LastCSMDate) ` why you did not here write like `(@LastCSMDate IS NULL OR X.LastCSMDeliveredDate=@LastCSMDate) ` ? for other paremeter you wrote like this way.

Comment: It's just a typo... fixed.

Comment: Why bother converting here? you asked me. i want compare only date not time that is why i convert there. my approach was right ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sir if it would be dynamic sql then how could i handle this operation for which i was getting error. `WHERE CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)>= @offset  AND CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)< (@offset+@PageSize)`

Comment: Instead of converting to string you can cast to `Date`. That would mane the code more readable as the intent would be very clear: `AND (@LastCSMDate IS NULL OR CAST(X.LastCSMDeliveredDate as Date)= CAST(@LastCSMDate as Date))`.

Comment: To answer the original question, you need to explicitly cast the int to varchar to prevent sql server's attempt to implicitly convert the string to int: 
`'<some string value>' + cast(<some int value> as varchar(11))` . The maximum number of chars you might need is 11, since the largest int is 10 digits long and the smallest is also 10 digits long but also has a `-` sign.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sir as per you said i did that conversion in my dynamic sql but getting same conversion error. `    WHERE CAST(X.RowNumber AS VARCHAR(11))>=CAST('+@offset+' AS VARCHAR) AND CAST(X.RowNumber AS INT)<CAST('+(@offset+@PageSize)+' AS VARCHAR(11))'
`  what i am missing still ? please guide me. thanks

Comment: should be `WHERE X.RowNumber >= '+cast(@offset as varchar(11)) +'`

Comment: Sir i did it but getting this error `    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastCSMDeliveredDate DESC) AS INT) AS 'RowNumber',
    ID,
    Ticker,
    c.ClientName,
    Earnings,
    PrePost,
    IIF([QC-ViewAllContent] IS NULL,0,1) HasViewAllContent,
    IIF([QCCommentsContent] IS NULL,0,1) HasQCCommentsContent,
    InsertedOn,
    LastCSMDeliveredDate,
    Action,
    UserName
    from tblLastCSMDelivered csm JOIN tblClient c
    ON csm.ClientCode=c.ClientCode
    WHERE LastCSMDeliveredDate IS NOT NULL) X
    WHERE X.RowNumber>=0 AND X.RowNumber<10' is not a valid identifier.`

Comment: it's quite hard to read the code in the comments. Please use something like [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to paste the code in and comment with a link. I'll try to see if anything pops out

Comment: Sorry by mistake i added the code in your post. please see that code under edit you can understand.

Comment: Please don't edit the code into my post. either edit it into your own question or paste in in some online fiddle. I didn't see a problem in the code you've pasted.